# Remove Injected HTML from Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am injecting validator errors next to the content that is incorrect.  Once clicked, all the injected html displays correctly. If the bad data is corrected, I would like to have the injected HTML removed.  I have tried view ID and class using .remove and .removeClass but seem to be having some problems getting the injected html removed. Any help?  I think I am having problems selecting the right selector. Also, the code and IDs are obviously generated by .Net.

### HTML

```
<div id="C004_ctl00_ctl00_C006_ctl00_ctl00_expandableTarget_write" class="sfFieldWrp" style="display:;">
    <textarea name="C004$ctl00$ctl00$C006$ctl00$ctl00$textBox_write" rows="5" cols="20" id="C004_ctl00_ctl00_C006_ctl00_ctl00_textBox_write" class="sfTxt">Enter your question or comments here... </textarea>
</div>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
var comments = $("#C004_ctl00_ctl00_C006_ctl00_ctl00_textBox_write").val();

if (comments == "" || comments == "Enter your question or comments here... ") {
    $("#C004_ctl00_ctl00_C006_ctl00_ctl00_expandableTarget_write").css("position", "relative");
    $("#C004_ctl00_ctl00_C006_ctl00_ctl00_textBox_write").after("<span style='color:red;font-family:Arial;font-size:18pt;padding-left:15px;position:absolute;bottom:60px;right:30px;' class='commentsError'>*</span>");
    event.preventDefault();
} else {
    $("#C004_ctl00_ctl00_C006_ctl00_ctl00_textBox_write").find("span").removeClass("commentsError");
}
```

ANSWER: $("#C004_ctl00_ctl00_C012_ctl00_ctl00_dropDown").next("span").remove("span");  This is how I was able to access that selector as well as remove the span entirely instead of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the error with `.after()` then use `.find()` to remove it.

`.after()` add the element after the selected node while `.find()` search for a descendant of the node.

The using `.next()`, it is the method selecting the next (sibling) element :

```
$("#C004_ctl00_ctl00_C006_ctl00_ctl00_textBox_write").next("span")
```

Comment: $("#C004_ctl00_ctl00_C012_ctl00_ctl00_dropDown").next("span").removeClass("ddlError");   is not working.

Comment: @HeatherRoberts I see that's an other element. The code provided will only work if the span is right next to the selected one. If your DOM isn't always the same, check other DOM navigation methodes like prev, siblings, closest, find, children and etc.

Comment: $("#C004_ctl00_ctl00_C006_ctl00_ctl00_textBox_write").next("span").removeClass("commentsError");  My apologies.  I am trying to get this working on multiple elements.

Comment: @HeatherRoberts do you have any error in console? And what do you mean by "not working"? the class is still on the DOM node?

Comment: Would it be easier to remove the entire span element rather than the class?

Comment: @HeatherRoberts With your code, i would remove it since you had an error everytime (repeating the error will add more "*"). And from what i see, you input your styles on the DOM and not with the CSS files on the class. The class is probly removed but not your style, that's probly why you think it is not working.

Comment: $("#C004_ctl00_ctl00_C012_ctl00_ctl00_dropDown").next("span").remove("span"); was the winner!  Thanks for getting me down the right path.